# Allowing multiple differently shaped interfaces as TypeScript return types

Tags: typescript, interface, unions, typeguards

I have a function that takes a few parameters and generates objects that will be passed into an external process. Sine I have no control over the shapes that need to be ultimately created, I have to be able to take some varying parameters to my function and assemble them into the appropriate objects. Here's a really basic example that exhibits the issue I'm having:

```
interface T1A {
    type: 'type1';
    index: number;
}

interface T1B {
    type: 'type1';
    name: string;
}

interface T2A {
    type: 'type2';
    index: number;
}

interface T2B {
    type: 'type2';
    name: number;
}

function hello(type: 'type1' | 'type2'): T1A | T1B | T2A | T2B {
    return {type, index: 3}
}
```

This particular function complains that 'type1' is not assignable to 'type2'. I read a bit about type guarding and figured out how to make this simple example happpy:

```
function hello(type: 'type1' | 'type2'): T1A | T1B | T2A | T2B {
    if (type === 'type1') {
        return {type, index: 3}
    } else {
        return {type, index: 3}
    }
}
```

However, I don't see why this is necessary. The type check is doing absolutely nothing to the return value's possibilities. Based on the fact my parameter takes only one of two explicit strings, the single return statement is guaranteed to return one of T1A or T2A. In my actual use-case I have more types and parameters but the way I've assigned them it's always guaranteed to return at least one of the specified interfaces. It seems that the union is not really a 'this OR this' when dealing with interfaces. I am trying to break up my code to handle each individual type, but when there's 8 different possibilities, I end up with a lot of extra if/else blocks which seem useless.

I have also tried using types `type T1A = {...};`

Am I misunderstanding something about the unions or is this a bug, or a simpler way to deal with it?

Comment: Well, your function realistically only returns `T1A | T2A` and it cannot return the other two interfaces. If you do mark the return type as those two, then the compilation passes correctly.

Comment: I did think about that and was going to put that note in the post, but that's not quite the issue because the second snippet with the if/else also cannot be T1B or T2B but it passes the compiler just fine. And I can make a slightly more complicated function which does return all four possibilities, but still complains about the 'type1' cannot be assigned to 'type2' issue illustrated above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't, in general, perform the kind of propagation of unions up from properties.  That is, while every value of the type `{foo: string | number}` should be assignable to the type `{foo: string} | {foo: number}`, the compiler does not see those as mutually assignable:

```
declare let unionProp: { foo: string | number };
const unionTop: { foo: string } | { foo: number } = unionProp; // error!
```

Aside from weird things that happen when you start mutating properties of such types, it's just too much work in general for the compiler to do that all the time, especially when you have multiple union properties.  A [relevant comment in microsoft/TypeScript#12052](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052#issuecomment-258653766) says:

> this sort of equivalence only holds for types with a single property and isn't true in the general case. For example, it wouldn't be correct to consider `{ x: "foo" | "bar", y: string | number }` to be equivalent to `{ x: "foo", y: string } | { x: "bar", y: number }` because the first form allows all four combinations whereas the second form only allows two specific ones.

So it's not a bug per se, but a limitation: the compiler is only going to spend so much time playing with unions to see if some code is valid.

---

In TypeScript 3.5, [support was added](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#smarter-union-type-checking) to do the above computations specifically for the case of [discriminated unions](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).  If your union has properties that can be used to distinguish between members of the union (which means singleton types like [string literals](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types), [numeric literals](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types), `undefined`, or `null`) in [at least some member of the union](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#non-unit-types-as-union-discriminants), then the compiler will verify your code the way you want it.

This is why it suddenly works if you change `T1A | T2A | T1B | T2B` to just `T1A | T2A`, and can be a possible answer to your question:

```
function hello(type: 'type1' | 'type2'): T1A | T2A | T1B | T2B {
    const x: T1A | T2A = { type, index: 3 }; // okay
    return x;
}
```

The latter is a discriminated union: the `type` property tells you which member you have.  But the former is not: the `type` property can distinguish between `T1A | T1B` and `T2A | T2B`, but there's no property to further subdivide.  No, the mere absence of `index` or `name` in the type does not count as a discriminant, since a value of type `T1A` *may have* a `name` property; types in TypeScript are not [exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).

The above code works because the compiler can verify that `x` is of type `T1A | T2A`, and can then verify that `T1A | T2A` is a subtype of the full `T1A | T2A | T1B | T2B`.  So if you're happy with a two-step process, this is a possible solution for you.

---

If you want `T1A | T2A | T1B | T2B` to be a discriminated union, you need to modify the constituent types' definitions so as to truly discriminate by at least one common property.  Like, say, this:

```
interface T1A {
    type: 'type1';
    index: number;
    name?: never;
}

interface T1B {
    type: 'type1';
    name: string;
    index?: never;
}

interface T2A {
    type: 'type2';
    index: number;
    name?: never;
}

interface T2B {
    type: 'type2';
    name: number;
    index?: never;
}
```

By adding those optional properties of type `never`, you can now use `type`, `name`, *and* `index` as discriminants.  The `name` and `index` properties will sometimes be `undefined`, a singleton type that is supported to distinguish types.  And then this works:

```
function hello(type: 'type1' | 'type2'): T1A | T2A | T1B | T2B {
    return { type, index: 3 }; // okay
}
```

---

So those are two options.  Another option which is always available in such situations where you know something is safe but the compiler doesn't, is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
function hello2(type: 'type1' | 'type2') {
    return { type, index: 3 } as T1A | T2A | T1B | T2B
}
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEEQBd4FcB2BLA9hgCjDgA4Bc8A3vAGY47kDOyMWGA5vAD7wZoC2AIxAx4AXwDcAKDB4m6bHgAqJclVr14TFuzFdKNOuV6DhugLzzcBIsXHwA9PfjCiMAIST4kjFD4gGxFBgCAAiWAxgLHyUnvBxrMjC1EEIigCMAIIxcTk5yACexCDkAOQFRWklUrm5rKAAHkb8QjDVOaKSsfEYiTDJwfDpAELZNXHlxfBlhSCVbWM+fozMrGzzYp21PUkpgwBMWRRdNROlE3tVx1sNTSatxx3HCTsDinsjR2PjM2czF+u5RaTYwtdaPXLUTBgZBWeAACxAEAgOAAFKcphNKnppkULgBKcjpLLcN7EwZpEYk96jMYyDByRrksmk+AWKgTAA08DqIEZAGYxACcnBkGgYBh4PUwZscpCMNDYQikTg9mifhiZljuDiQPiaTURWKJeyZlyefzdFAGEy9CySRTbe8Hp1HkCArsALJQADWIDCESi+uefV2RP1uXROrmVxy5tuoJjcSBAH4jCAAG7CaVPbYh14Oz5fSOYy5fHi+SZaVZC7oNVM8DNZ5053r9VIHcN5dU6-6J7kYG48ZpNssptOZ+65cGx3Nt-YfPvFv6lr5A+Mjr7m+sYRuT9oyuJyhV4eGI5Fqoq-ColbHnEoEm1U5kOqkLsuG8X6Tn9wcCiTNx4gA)